# How do I get a Golang Database connection pool to manage connections to multiple hosts in a cluster?

Tags: postgresql, go, replication, connection-pooling, postgresql-bdr

I'm setting up [bi-direction replication](http://bdr-project.org) between four PostgreSQL workers, and I'd like to have my Go database connection pool handle connections to all four. It ought to be able to create multiple connections to them all, randomly select one for any given query, and fail over when a connection drops. Is this doable in the Go database library? Or should I just use [pgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io) and not try to get [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) or [pgx](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx) to handle that balancing?

Comment: Connection pool in golang is per `configuration` (in case of PostgreSQL per schema, for MySQL you can use "same" connection to access multiple database/schema in the same server). If you need to connect to multiple servers, you need to create different connection pool for each server, then manage it manually. IMHO, in your case, you should use pgBouncer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connection pool in golang is created whenever you call `sql.Open(driverName, dataSourceName)`, where `dataSourceName` is driver specific `configuration` for connecting to database. Whenever we change the `configuration` (i.e. changing host address, schema, username, etc) we need to open new connection, thus new connection pool will be created. If a driver can handle load balancing, it should be configurable in `dataSourceName`, e.g. as in [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j/) high availability configuration.

AFAIK, load balancing not yet supported in [lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) and [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx). In your case, to connect to database servers in cluster, you need to open different connection pool for each server, then manage the connections (and perform load balancing) manually. This approach needs a lot of work to be done. I think it is better to use pgBouncer.